# I cant import MapView for android project

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

```
public class ActivityGoogleMaps extends MapActivity {// map view shows as an error
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

}

I try to import this:
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

but when i type com.    - google doesnt appear..

Comment: Have you set Google Apis as project build target?

Comment: Project---> properties..change sdk?? or do you mean something else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1- Go to Project Properties
2- From android tab, select Google API for your target platform
(for 2.2, select Google APIs-Platform 2.2 and things like that)

I think this can solve the problem

Comment: Thanks..but I picked 3.2 as my max version of sdk

Answer (score 0):

you will have to add map.jar to libs. though it is automatically added when we extends MapActivity.

Comment: Kamal..that doesnt tell me anything